# Selecting point/feature in layer using coordinates

Tags: pyqgis

I want to select a feature using my own coordinates.

Is that possible in PyQGIS?

I mean i enter my own coordinates and the program should select the feature at that specific coordinate if there's an feature at that point.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please show us what you have tried and what is going wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

This pyqgis code finds features in the active layer that intersect with a specified point. It iterates through the layer's features, checks for intersections with the point and prints the feature id

```
# point coordinate pair
import qgis
x=346847.9955105399
y=126063.99001055231

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

point = qgis.core.QgsPointXY(x, y) #create point
point_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point) #point geometry

for a in layer.getFeatures(): #iterate over the active layer
    if a.geometry().intersects(point_geometry):
        print(a.id())#print intersected object's ids
```